# mysql SELECT WHERE LIKE multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

Nothing is being returned when I execute this query!

I'm trying to have multiple values for same column

```
SELECT * FROM `users` where Number='1212' AND Number='0921'
```

please, can you help?

Comment: No number exists that is both 1212 and 0921 at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Change the 'AND' to an 'OR'. A number (or anything else in a table column for that matter) cannot be both values at the same time

```
 SELECT * FROM `users` where Number='1212' OR Number='0921'
```

Where you need rows where an element can be one of a number of values, it is common to use IN instead of repeated OR clauses, as this makes the expression clearer:

```
 SELECT * FROM `users` where Number IN ('1212','0921');
```

As one of your Number values has a leading zero, I presume it is genuinely a string. You might want to name your columns better.

Answer (score 1):

Or better use the `IN` operator, so you could filter for even more values:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` where Number IN ('1212', '0921');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> SELECT * FROM users where Number=1212 OR Number=0921

Answer (score 0):

Change AND by OR, if you need to check equality with more values you could just use `SELECT * FROM users WHERE number IN(1212, 0921, 1452, 1265);`